# TortoiseSVN is running very slow

Tags: tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN application is running very slow.
Ít waits too long when trying to open Repo-browser or updating. It keeps showing the message "Please wait while the repository browser is initializing".
Then after waiting for 10 mins or so, it shows up the credential window, and then again a long wait.
I installed command line sliksuberversion, and updates from command line using subversion run as normal, from which I deduced that there is no OS or network related issue.
I enabled debugLogs, and got the following:

[image: Debug logs]

The timestamps show the delay. Eventually the server connection times out, due to the delay.
Please suggest.

Comment: What version of TSVN? If you have an anti-virus software, try disabling it (or excluding the working-directory from the real-time protection).

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.9.0, Build 26652 - 64 Bit

Comment: The problem might be a reverse DNS lookup on SVN server's IP address during SSL handshake. Make sure there's reverse DNS record for SVN server.

Comment: I also noticed that I am able to ping the svn server using the machine name, but could not ping it by ip address. In my repository address, I am using the machine name, and since I am able to ping the machine, I am assuming that it should work.

Comment: try TSVN 1.9.1: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.1/

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your suggestions and time on this. The issue was traced to ICMP not accessible in server machine, because it was not different subnet. I was able to ping the machine using domain name, but not by IP (this statement is correct, and it was not the other way round). What was surprising was the subversion was working fine, but not tortoise, which probably indicates that tortoisesvn has an additional network step (ping or something else) in their process over subversion.        Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your suggestions and time on this. The issue was traced to ICMP not accessible in server machine, because it was not different subnet. I was able to ping the machine using domain name, but not by IP (this statement is correct, and it was not the other way round). What was surprising was the subversion was working fine, but not tortoise, which probably indicates that tortoisesvn has an additional network step (ping or something else) in their process over subversion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same. It worked before, and started after I was moved from cubicles to cubicles with maybe network reset although my IP address remains the same.

It works again after run  `ipconfig /renew` and restart TortoiseSVN client.